# FileZilla: overwrite if source folder has fewer files

Tags: filezilla

I have an "Images" folder on my remote server with 20 images. In my local copy of the Images folder I updated some images and deleted a few, and ended up with 15 images left.

Now I want to re-upload the whole folder on the server, so the new Images folder completely replaces the one that's currently on the server, and so I end up with Images folder on the server that has 35 images.

I use FileZilla, and when I simply drag the new Images folder onto the remote directory to replace the existing one, and hit 'Overwrite', it overwrites the images that were changed, but keeps the total of 20 images on the server.

What I want FileZilla to do is to replace the WHOLE folder with the new one that has updated images AND the new image quantity (15).

Is there a simple way to do that in FileZilla?
If anybody can point me in the right direction I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Now in FileZilla View -> Directory comparison is a really good solution, you can visually see the files that are only on the server and delete them quickly. I found I liked it better than something that would delete them automatically since for example there are actually extra subfolders on the server side I need to keep.

Comment: Thanks! FileZilla View -> Directory comparison is great!

Answer (score 1):

Delete the remote files and reupload? If your're expecting advanced fileset operations, FTP is the wrong protocol.

Comment: Good answer, don't over complicate things, if you want the whole remote directory replaced with the new, just blow out the old and re-upload.

Comment: Really? So while you are transferring people just get a 404? The problem seems legitimate to me, I came here trying to do the same thing, its not an "advanced fileset operation" it's updating the server and you'd think FileZilla could do it, it's kind of a simple actually.

Answer (score 1):

Ipswitch FTP does exactly that - compare files and let's you replace missing files, replace whole directories etc.Yes you pay for it but its not very expensive.

Wish Filezilla would do it - as some of you say, it's a simple procedure. And why show the differences if you then can't do anything about them? That's why Filezilla mess me off a little.